# Material Ui Datepicker is giving error: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement a Datepicker in my React Project using the Material UI's DatePicker. I initially tried to do what [this](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/) site said. After that didn't work, I tried a simpler approach and tried what [this](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker) site said. Both those approaches give this error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `AddScreen`.
```

My CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-karmapact-app-bghgp?file=/App.js (Datepicker is implemented in /Screens/AddScreen.js)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Package is mismatch :

```
  "@date-io/date-fns": "2.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "latest",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "4.0.0-alpha.12"
```

Instead you need to use these:

```
"@date-io/date-fns": "v1",
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "latest",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "latest",
```

2. For using `KeyboardTimePicker` you also need to provide `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` which is not present .

Here is code for `AddScreen`

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-dialog"
          label="Date picker dialog"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
        <KeyboardTimePicker
          margin="normal"
          id="time-picker"
          label="Time picker"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change time"
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-demo-forked-4gvbl?file=/Screens/AddScreen.js:0-946